# Android - Layout_gravity="Bottom" does not go to the end on the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I'm having stupid issues with a LinearLayout.
I'm requesting the NO_TITLE feature before the setContentView and I have  a Xaml looking like this :

```
<LinearLayout
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E600323d"
tools:context="mycontext.Activities.dialogSignal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="center"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="SOME TEXT"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="10%"/>

<!-- FIRST ROW -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:onClick="bruitNavigate"
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- SECOND ROW -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- THIRD ROW -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/SomeString"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descriptionContentSignal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="SomeString"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/centralbutton"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/accept"
        android:onClick="closeView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, the last LinearLayout (the one containing only two ImageButtons) does not align with the bottom of the screen and is floating somewhere depending of the screen size.

I'm applying this style to get a transparent background :

```
    <style name="dialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

If anyone has met the same issue, I would love to get ideas...
Thank you for your time !

Comment: try adding fitsSystemWindows attribute (true or false, can't remember which you will need) to your main layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your last `Linearlayout` Make the Height to `match parent`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center">

</LinearLayout>
```

**OR**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"   //add this
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center">
```

**Explanation:**

All the items inside this `LinearLayout` take some space, make sure that the last item, which is the `LinearLayout` wrapping the buttons, stretches to occupy all the remaining space. Set `android:layout_weight="1"` or make the height `match_parent`

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot !
Could you explain how changing the height to match parent made it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your layout to bottom, please use RelativeLayout as a parent and set view accordingly. Or you can use LinearLayout with weight where you need to set weight 1 to middle layout, top and bottom set automatically based on screen size.

Layout weight for LinearLayout : refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

RelativeLayout : refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```